# Can I get a relational intersection or difference using Slick 2?

Tags: sql, scala, slick, intersect, relational-algebra

I'm using Slick versian 2.0.0-M3.  If I have two [`Query`](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.0-M3/api/#scala.slick.lifted.Query)s representing relations of the same type, I see there is a `union` operator to inclusively disjoin them, but I don't see a comparable operator for obtaining their intersection nor their difference.  Do such operators not exist in Slick?

I think the foregoing explains what I'm looking for, but if not, here's an example.  I have the suppliers table:

```
case class Supplier(snum: String, sname: String, status: Int, city: String)

class Suppliers(tag: Tag) extends Table[Supplier](tag, "suppliers") {
  def snum  = column[String]("snum")
  def sname = column[String]("sname")
  def status   = column[Int]("status")
  def city     = column[String]("city")
  def * = (snum, sname, status, city) <> (Supplier.tupled, Supplier.unapply _)
}
val suppliers = TableQuery[Suppliers]
```

If I want to know about suppliers that either are in a particular city or have a particular status, I see how to use `Query.union` for that:

```
scala> val thirtySuppliers = suppliers.filter(_.status === 30)
thirtySuppliers: scala.slick.lifted.Query[Suppliers,Suppliers#TableElementType] = scala.slick.lifted.WrappingQuery@166f63a

scala> val londonSuppliers = suppliers.filter(_.city === "London")
londonSuppliers: scala.slick.lifted.Query[Suppliers,Suppliers#TableElementType] = scala.slick.lifted.WrappingQuery@1bea855

scala> (thirtySuppliers union londonSuppliers).foreach(println)
Supplier(S1,Smith,20,London)
Supplier(S4,Clark,20,London)
Supplier(S3,Blake,30,Paris)
Supplier(S5,Adams,30,Athens)
```

No problem.  But what if I want only the suppliers that are *both* in a particular city *and* have a particular status?  Seems as if I ought to be able to do something like:

```
(thirtySuppliers intersect londonSuppliers).foreach(println)
```

Or if I want the suppliers in a particular city *except* the ones that have a particular status.  Can I not do something like:

```
(thirtySuppliers except londonSuppliers).foreach(println)
```

SQL has `UNION`, `INTERSECT`, and `EXCEPT` operations, and Slick's `Query` class has a `union` method that builds an SQL query using SQL's `UNION`, but I'm not seeing [`Query`](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.0-M3/api/#scala.slick.lifted.Query) methods in Slick for deriving intersections nor differences.  Am I missing them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a pull request that implements this. It will likely make it into 2.0 or 2.1. https://github.com/slick/slick/pull/242 We still need to figure out some details and clean up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

The operations are pretty much composable in that an intersect can just be two filters. For instance

```
val intersect = suppliers.filter(_.status === 30).filter(_.city === "London")
```

or except:

```
val except= suppliers.filter(_.city === "London").filterNot(_.status === 30)
```

Comment: What you say is true in this case, as my two operand relations are restrictions of the same base table.  However, I am interested in being able to do the operations in the general case of any two `Query`s (with appropriate columns).  Perhaps I ought to have used two separate base tables in my example.