# How to do sql queries with intersect with Slick?

Tags: sql, scala, slick

I am trying to build sql queries with slick where I need to intersect the results. I can build it with union (from [Slick docs](https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.2.0/queries.html#unions)):

```
val q1 = coffees.filter(_.price < 8.0)
val q2 = coffees.filter(_.price > 9.0)

val unionQuery = q1 union q2
// compiles to SQL (simplified):
//   select x8."COF_NAME", x8."SUP_ID", x8."PRICE", x8."SALES", x8."TOTAL"
//     from "COFFEES" x8
//     where x8."PRICE" < 8.0
//   union select x9."COF_NAME", x9."SUP_ID", x9."PRICE", x9."SALES", x9."TOTAL"
//     from "COFFEES" x9
//     where x9."PRICE" > 9.0
```

I need to do something similar to this:

```
val q1 = coffees.filter(_.price < 8.0)
val q2 = coffees.filter(_.price > 9.0)

val intersectQuery = q1 intersect q2
// compiles to SQL (simplified):
//   select x8."COF_NAME", x8."SUP_ID", x8."PRICE", x8."SALES", x8."TOTAL"
//     from "COFFEES" x8
//     where x8."PRICE" < 8.0
//   intersect select x9."COF_NAME", x9."SUP_ID", x9."PRICE", x9."SALES", x9."TOTAL"
//     from "COFFEES" x9
//     where x9."PRICE" > 9.0
```

I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20042922/can-i-get-a-relational-intersection-or-difference-using-slick-2) that there was a PR meant to do that but it's from 10 years ago and I can't see that code in the current source code. I am using Scala 2.13.

I've tried:

- Looking for the method in the [Query object](https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.1.0/api/#slick.lifted.Query).
- Going through the [official docs](https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.2.0/queries.html)
- Look for creative methods or what other people do in this situations

Comment: the intersection is a simpoler to use inner join, so ysou take both queries a subqueires and join themby the columns that are equal

Comment: The above INTERSECT will return no rows. (X8.PRICE and X9.PRICE will never be equal.) Perhaps you want something else. A [mcve] would clarify.

Comment: @nbk . inner join has different result and different performance than intersect https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51775718/is-there-a-fundamental-difference-between-intersect-and-inner-join

Comment: inner join with proper indexes are fast, faster as everything else-

Comment: Again, different result

Comment: @jarlh I am totally fine for the query in the example to return empty set if that is what is supposed to return. I am looking for how to make an intersect query.
Anyway here is a sample with potentially non empty result

  val q1 = coffees.filter(_.price < 8.0).map(_.name)
  val q2 = icecreams.filter(_.price > 9.0).map(_.name)

  val interQuery = q1 intersect q2
   //compiles to SQL (simplified):
   //  select x8."COF_NAME"
   //    from "COFFEES" x8
   //    where x8."PRICE" < 8.0
   //  intersect select x9."ICE_NAME"
   //    from "ICECREAMS" x9
   //    where x9."PRICE" > 9.0

Comment: Why do you want to create a query that will never return anything?

Comment: @jarlh, as I said: I am interested in the syntax. Eventually queries do not return anything and that is a valid result one needs to handle, my code is not actually composing the logic of the query, I am just handling and translating the query. Also I provided you with a sample of a query that would potentially return non-empty results

Comment: Which one - the UNION query? UNION <> INTERSECT.

Comment: @jarlh in the comment above. Pasting again:  val q1 = coffees.filter(.price < 8.0).map(.name) val q2 = icecreams.filter(.price > 9.0).map(.name) val interQuery = q1 intersect q2 //compiles to SQL (simplified): // select x8."COF_NAME" // from "COFFEES" x8 // where x8."PRICE" < 8.0 // intersect select x9."ICE_NAME" // from "ICECREAMS" x9 // where x9."PRICE" > 9.0